# nuxt3: how pass data through slot

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, pass-data

i have component sidebar with filterOptions. i want pass value of filterOptionsto pages/collections/index.

component sidebar

```
const filterOptions = ref{ //some filters}
const handleSetFilter = () => {//login set filter}
const handleClearFilter = () => {// filterOptions.value = {}}
```

in layouts/collectionLayout.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Header/>
            <slot>
               <SideBar/>
            </slot>
        <Footer/>
    </div>
</template>
<script setup>
</script>
```

in collections/index.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
     
    </div>
</template>
<script setup>
 /// i want handle product filter with filterOptions from SideBar component
</script>
```

Comment: Why not use pinia & composable?